# Repeated password prompt with Maven deploy-file to scp repository

Tags: maven-2, deployment, scp

I'm trying to deploy an artifact to a remote repository accessible via scp and having a problem with repeated password prompts. My settings.xml contains this fragment:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>example.com</id>
        <username>myusername</username>
        <password>mypassword</password>
        <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
        <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
    </server>
</servers>
```

The command line interaction looks like this:

```
$ mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=11.2.0.1.0 -DrepositoryId=example.com -Durl=scp://example.com/maven2/
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'deploy'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [deploy:deploy-file] (aggregator-style)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [deploy:deploy-file {execution: default-cli}]
Keyboard interactive required, supplied password is ignored
Password: : mypassword
Uploading: scp://example.com/maven2//com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.1.0/ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar
2061K uploaded  (ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar)
[INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from example.com
Keyboard interactive required, supplied password is ignored
Password: : mypassword
[INFO] repository metadata for: 'artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6' could not be found on repository: example.com, so will be created
[INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'artifact com.oracle:ojdbc6'
Keyboard interactive required, supplied password is ignored
Password: : mypassword
[INFO] Uploading project information for ojdbc6 11.2.0.1.0
Keyboard interactive required, supplied password is ignored
Password: : mypassword
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 30 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Sep 02 13:03:33 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/90M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There are several problems here:

1. I'm prompted for a password even though it is is specified in the settings.xml
2. The password is echoed back on the console
3. It does not remember the password and instead asks me 4 times.

How can I configure maven so it either uses a password from settings.xml or asks me once without echoing my password to the screen?

**Edit:** This was on Ubuntu linux, a collegue just reproduced the same problem on Windows XP. As mounting the repository to a local path is not an option on Windows, I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Gotta love those oracle version numbers ... ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar.  .....  I'm really looking forward to java version 7.0.0.1.0

Comment: 5 years later, I have the same bug: any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have since installed [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) as an repository manager and are using the web interface to upload third party jars.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following on the maven-users list:

the sshd on the server used `PasswordAuthentication no`. After
switching to `yes` my maven config works fine.

Comment: It worked for me. Then, I used 'sudo /etc/init.d/sshd restart' to apply effect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set either the [repositoryId](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) in your pom to use the correct server entry from the settings.xml, cause it looks like you don't set that so it uses the id: remote-repository. or did you changed the settings.xml accordingly.

Comment: I don't have a pom since this is an external artifact which I downloaded. The repositoryId is specified on the command line via `-DrepositoryId=example.com`. The server settings seem to be used by maven since it does not ask me for my username, which is only set in settings.xml.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I'm currently mounting the remote repository using sshfs and then using a file url in the maven command:

```
$ sudo adduser jh fuse
$ sudo mkdir -p /mnt/example.com/maven2
$ sudo chown -R jh:jh /mnt/example.com
$ sshfs username@example.com:/maven2 /mnt/example.com/maven2
$ mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=11.2.0.1.0 -Durl=file:///mnt/example.com/maven2/repository/
```

Configuring the server in settings.xml is not needed in this case, the repositoryId need not be specified on the command line and I can use shell autocompletion on the file url.

I would still be interested if anyone can reproduce the problem or suggest a solution using maven standards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact solution, but at least the following works:

Create a server entry in the file ~/.m2/settings.xml:

```
<server>
  <id>example-dist</id>
  <username>myusername</username>
  <password>ignored</password>
</server>
```

Perform the deploy or deploy:deploy-file as follows:

```
mvn deploy -DrepositoryId=example-dist
```

You'll be asked for the password for the supplied username - the password in the settings.xml is ignored.

If you don't want to supply passwords each time, you can do so by generated a ssh key using ssh-keygen. The generated public key you'll have to store in the authorized_keys files at the distribution server (for a better explanation, see several tutorials on the web or the man page).

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems related.
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/WAGON-323
Im am getting the message "Keyboard interactive required, supplied password is ignored" - even with wagon-ssh-2.4.
Tried to set `<interactiveMode>false</interactiveMode>` but then auth fails right away.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Gerbrand's response, you can skip providing user credentials with ssh keys. The steps are the following:

1. If you do not have one yet, generate a private/public key pair with `ssh-keygen`. Let's say you store the private key in `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`
2. Copy the public key to the destination server with `ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa USER@serverhostname`
3. Change your `settings.xml` to use your keys instead of password

   ```
   <server>
       <id>serverhostname</id>
       <username>USER</username>
       <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>
       <!-- Note there is no password tag specified -->
   </server>
   ```

Next time you need to login to the server via Maven, no password will be requested.